# handle Submit and PreventDefault using react testing library

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write test case which has submit type and has prevent default inside submit button. It looks like event is not firing in test case.

form.js

```
click me
```

```
  function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

my test case

```
  it("Click with correct credentials", async () => {
    await act(() => {
      render(<XYZ />, container);
    });

    const submitLogin = screen.getByTestId("submit-login-btn");

    act(() => {
      submitLogin.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true }));
    });

    await expect(global.window.location.pathname).toEqual("/expectedPath");
 });
```

Onclick on "click me", it should redirect to /expectedPath. But test case failing, I am guessing its due to submit button and prevent default.

Comment: Please give a [mre].